# Retriving the url of a Hyperlink column which is in a sharepoint list, using Client object model

Tags: sharepoint-clientobject

function IfModuleSucceded(sender, args) {

```
            var existingCount = existingItems.get_count();
            var existEnumerator = existingItems.getEnumerator();

            while (existEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                var currentmodule = existEnumerator.get_current();
                var URL = currentmodule.get_item("Request_URL");

                alert(URL);

            }

        }
```

In this Code i am trying to Retrieve the url of a Hyperlink column which is in a SharePoint list, using Client object model, but i have received an object. How could i get the Url out of this received object ????

when this code is executed, it gives the alert as "[Object Object]".
would anyone help me to sort this out ??

Comment: yehaaa...i found the anwser...i can use    var URL = currentmodule.get_item("Request_URL").get_url();

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be `alert(url.url)` as it's an object.

It will also have a property called description

Comment: thank you for your answer. i tried but it didn't work. i could get the url by using ".get_url()"

Answer (score 0):

The Hyperlink field has two properties: Description and Url.

You can access the properties like this: ObjectName.PropertyName

So for your URL object in your example, you can reach the properties like this: URL.Url and URL.Description

I found that Url and Description are case sensitive, so make sure you capitalize where necessary.

This worked great for me.